# Moving to WordPress and old CMS to a subfolder

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to move a website to WordPress and I need all thousands of its old Google indexes intact.

Consider the url is like this:
`www.mysite.com/article/1/test.html`

Now I move all root contents of my old CMS to a folder named OLD, so I expect now all old links to redirect to the subfolder like this:
`www.mysite.com/OLD/article/1/test.html`

For that I used these lines of code in my root `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It works with no problem. But my question is how can I install a new WordPress in root directory and have both new WordPress and the old one to keep all old links?

Comment: just put all the files on root directory but db keep diffrent  for  both

Answer (score 0):

How about backing up the old wordpress database. Create a new test directory at www.yoursite.com/test/ and install Wordpress there. And after you have created the new database for your test site import the backed up database.

When Install is complete go [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)

This might help you.